# Constructing a matrix with repeated eigenvalues and invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to construct a $3\times 3$ matrix where I have the following eigenvalues: $\lambda_1$ = 1, $\lambda_2$ = 1, and $\lambda_3$ = 2. In addition, I have the following invariant subspaces $R_1$ = span($[1,2,1]^T$, $[-2,1,0]^T$) and $R_2$ = span($[-1,-2,5]^T$). Can anybody give me an idea how to solve this problem. I know that $A-I$ and $A-2I$ are the nullspaces. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after a matrix $A$ such that $A.[1,2,1]^T=[1,2,1]^T$, that $A.[-2,1,0]^T=[-2,1,0]^T$, and that $A.[-1,-2,5]^T=2[-1,-2,5]^T$. So, if$$R=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-1\\2&1&-2\\1&0&5\end{bmatrix},$$then$$R^{-1}.A.R=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a change of basis to make your basis vectors $[1,2,1]^T, [-2,1,0]^T, [-1,-2,5]^T$. Then consider the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
acting ***in this new basis***. This will fix $R_1$ and $R_2$ and have the correct eigenvalues. To get the matrix in the original basis you will have to do a similarity transform.

The idea is that we know how the matrix should act on the vectors $[1,2,1]^T, [-2,1,0]^T, [-1,-2,5]^T$, so we express it in that basis, then we can transform it back to our original basis.